# How to integrate the following definite integral involving trigonometric function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate the following integral, which I have no idea. Thanks for your attention.
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^{\pi} e^{\sin\varphi(\cos\theta -\sin\theta)} \sin\varphi\, d \varphi$$
I tried to introduce another integral
$$J=\int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^{\pi} e^{\sin\varphi(\cos\theta -\sin\theta)}\cos\varphi\, d \varphi$$ and hope that this may lead to some relation between $I$ and $J$, but this idea seem does not work.

Comment: What have you tried? I have a pretty elegant solution in mind.

Comment: I tried to introduce another integral:
$$J=\int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^{\pi} e^{\sin\varphi(\cos\theta -\sin\theta)}\quad \cos\varphi d \varphi$$ but I failed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your efforts.

Comment: Parentheses would help.  The exponent could be $(\sin\varphi)(\cos\theta -\sin\theta)$ or $\sin(\varphi(\cos\theta -\sin\theta))$.

Answer (score 7):

Notice that

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\pi e^{\sin \varphi (\cos\theta - \sin \theta)}\sin\varphi\:d\varphi = \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}e^{x-y}\:dS$$

Therefore we can rotate the domain (a transformation invariance of the sphere) to obtain

$$I = \iint\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}e^{\sqrt{2}z}\:dS = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\pi e^{\sqrt{2}\cos\varphi}\sin\varphi\:d\varphi = \pi\sqrt{2} \left(e^\sqrt{2}-e^{-\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\pi e^{\sin \varphi (\cos\theta - \sin \theta)}\sin\varphi\:d\varphi\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\:d\varphi\sin\varphi\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta e^{\sqrt2\sin \varphi \sin\theta}\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\:d\varphi\sin\varphi\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(\sqrt2\sin \varphi \sin\theta)^n\\
&=&\int_0^\pi\:d\varphi\sin\varphi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(\sqrt2\sin \varphi)^n\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta (\sin\theta)^n\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(2n)!}\int_0^\pi\:d\varphi (\sin \varphi)^{2n+1}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta(\sin\theta)^{2n}\\
&=&2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{(2n+1)(2n)!}\\
&=&2\sqrt2\pi\sinh(\sqrt2).
\end{eqnarray}
Here
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta (\sin\theta)^{2n}=\frac{\sqrt \pi\Gamma(\frac12+n)}{2n!}, \int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta (\sin\theta)^{2n+1}=\frac{\sqrt \pi n!}{2\Gamma(\frac32+n)}$$
and
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)(2n)!}=\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}. $$